# Transparent action bar and status bar like Uber

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-statusbar

I've done a few researches on this topic but I couldn't found some solution for my App/ Activity.

1. I have tried to get a transparent action bar.

First, I have tried to change the themes in my AndroidManifest.xml:

**values/styles.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

and

**values-v21/styles.xml:**

```
  <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

But thats the result:

[image]

So I only get some light grey action bar with some gaps on the left/ right side.

Second, I have tried using `fitsSystemWindow="true"` and `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` in my layouts, but it also didn't fix the issue.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.poweranimal.letsgo.Application.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But I get the same output as before:( 2. In addition I have tried also the get a transparent status bar with:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

and

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

but this didn't work too (nothing has changed).

What I actually want is something like this:

[image]

Would be cool if anyone has a possible solution for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**1.** First, you have to change your `layout` structure to show `MAP` under transparent `Toolbar` & `StatusBar` and also to remove left and right `gap` from your existing `Toolbar`.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:elevation="1dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/sample_map">

            <!-- put your content here -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**2.** In your `MainActivity`, do below things to initialize `Toolbar` and make `Toolbar` and `StatusBar` as `transparent`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    // Toolbar :: Transparent
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("StackOverflow");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Status bar :: Transparent
    Window window = this.getWindow();

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    ...........
    .................. 
}
```

**3.** Apply below theme to your `MainActivity`.

**values/styles.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    .......
    ...........

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".EmptyActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

</activity>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**FYI**, I have just used an sample image of map in my content `LinearLayout` to show the behavior. For your case put all of your content(`searchbar, map`) inside it.

Hope this will help~

Comment: @FAT it gives me a transparent status bar but it's not completely transparent like in Uber.

Comment: After 10 pages of searching finally find this answer. Great!

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

Add the following code to your activity to set status bar transparent and for action bar you should try a custom action bar with transparent background.

```
  private void settingStatusBarTransparent() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(Color.BLACK);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            //setStatusBarTranslucent(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: The bottom nav bar also gets transparent. My buttons are overlapping with system buttons

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First of all add custom color in `colors.xml` like below:

```
<color name="transparent_white">#80FFFFFF</color>
```

Then Set this color as background of main layout of your `Where to?` xml file.

And in this line `#80` is opacity(in short, opposite of transparent) of color.

First two letters ahead of color:

1. **'#00'**  - Full Transparent color
2. **'#FF'** or **Not any define** - Full Non-Transparent Color

Change in XML with below and try

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent_white">
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: in your activity: Set Fullscreen Flag

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Now in manifest: Apply theme

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent"/>
```

in res/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
</style>
```

And set `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` in your `CoordinatorLayout`

- `fitsSystemWindows="false"` : draws the view normally, under the status
  bar because of the window flags you have set.
- `fitsSystemWindows="true"` : draws the view under the status
  bar because of the window flags you have set, but adds a top
  padding so that content is drawn below the status bar and they don't 
  overlap.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changes with your solution. If I set `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`the statusbar disappears.

Comment: `statusbar disappears`? it will get transperant.!. Btw..i use the code and it works for me well..you  should check the other answers then

Answer (score 0):

As my point of view first, you create custom action bar and set a background of action bar transparent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <ImageButton
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/btnBackButton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />


   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="39dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
       android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       android:src="@drawable/logo_header_new"
       android:visibility="visible"
       />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is set these properties in your theme:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Your activity / container layout you wish to have a transparent status bar needs this property set:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows=”true”
```

Hope that helps you