# Transparent Status bar android

Tags: android, android-statusbar, android-navigation-bar

I tried

setting the *statusBarColor* to *transparent*, but it leaves a shadow

setting the *windowTranslucentStatus* to *true*, but it leaves a shadow

mixed and matched the above properties with fitsSystemWindow... no success

doing the following achieves the goal of completely transparent status... but also makes the nav bar completely transparent

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
```

How can I make only the status bar 100% transparent without touching the navBar

minSdk: 21

target: 26

compile 26

Android studio 3.0 preview (latest as of 9/6/17)

Comment: this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43951266/8164071) might be helpful.

Comment: can you share the screenshot

Answer (score 2):

**I think you can't make status bar 100% transparent because activity has its own window background(default background is white you can set window background using             getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(int resID) or getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable drawable))**

> You can set colour to status bar and set colour opacity in hex form after setContentView() shown in below code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF"));
    }

//Here "#00FFFFFF" means opacity is 0% (first two digits 00) and colour is white (next FFFFFF character).
```

> Or in styles.xml (post-Lollipop versions only. Compatibility may be compromised)

```
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

> For setting opacity refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors) link

Comment: setting the alpha to 0 still provides a shadow. I guess one option is to make both status and navigation bar transparent and add bar with color where the nav bar should go. But it seems cheap

Comment: when you set alpha to 0 it shows window background colour by default its white (window background changes as per parent theme).

Comment: Oh, yea you're right. I had fitSystemWindows on and I hadn't seen that flag you added, thought it was another one. Thanks!

Comment: what the hell... doesn't work anymore. Not sure what happened. will report back if fixed

Comment: @John check the theme which you are applying. If you applied other theme to other activity then again you have to make these changes. I think it should work

Comment: I'm gonna assume that it was just android studio 3.0. Damn I wanted a pure XML solution but I need to add *getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_STABLE | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);* but the previews don't look the same as runtime

Comment: Try to use it in your onCreate not in xml.

Answer (score 0):

use this **hex colour #00000000** in status bar

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same under the same conditions

You right about FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, but it is the way (code in kotlin)

```
//onCreate
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0)
```

getStatusBarHeight:

```
private fun getStatusBarHeight(): Int {
    var result = 0
    val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)
    }
    return result
}
```

and way how to return your navigation bar - put this in your styles:

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```