# Toolbar disappears when adding app:elevation attribute

Tags: android

I want my AppCompat toolbar to be transparent with zero elevation.

Adding the `android:background` attribute makes the toolbar transparent, but adding `app:elevation` attribute just makes the toolbar disappear completely; the up-button and title disappear, and if the background is red or some other solid color, that color also disappears.

Any idea why?

Here is my AppBar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"


        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Try out this link - [Transparent Toolbar like Uber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43951266/6587502)

Answer (score 3):

you just have to write `findViewById(R.id.appBar).bringToFront();` in java file.
Hope it helps you?